# How to enable "memory.usage", "disk.usage", "disk.device.usage" of ceilometer?

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I use `Kolla` to deploy `OpenStack`, but they are now None.
[Metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0WQx.png)

[image: Metric]

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue in `Kolla` and an issue in `Ceilometer`.

The OpenStack compute service must be configured to use Telemetry. Then, Ceilometer can extract CPU, memory and disk usage from the VMs. Add the following in `/etc/nova/nova.conf` on all the compute nodes:

```
[DEFAULT]
...
instance_usage_audit = True
instance_usage_audit_period = hour
notify_on_state_change = vm_and_task_state
compute_monitors= cpu.virt_driver

[oslo_messaging_notifications]
...
driver = messagingv2
```

https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/latest/install/install-compute-rdo.html#configure-compute-to-use-telemetry

I suggest using the latest `Ceilometer` release (`10.0.0` or `Queens`):

https://releases.openstack.org/teams/telemetry.html
https://docs.openstack.org/releasenotes/ceilometer/queens.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18779727)

Comment: Thanks for the info @Edric . I've updated my answer with the required info.

Comment: @Edric, I've updated my answer with the required info. Could you remove the down vote if the answer looks fine?